Casting a model field to an enum collection in Laravel
I have an enum JobCategory of company departments.
A Subscriber can subscribe to multiple of these, so I'm casting in the model casts() function as per the docs:
public function casts(): array
{
    return [
        'subscribed_categories' => AsEnumCollection::of(JobCategory::class),
    ];
}

This saves into a json field and all write operations work fine (tested in the model and in tinker).
However, when I read a model instance I would expect that field to be a collection of the enum, ie Collection<JobCategory>, but it's just an array of the enum values, eg ["marketing", "operations"].
Surely this should be being cast in both directions?
(PHP 8.3, Laravel 11.35.0)

AsEnumCollection cast works for serializing and deserializing attributes, but it needs to explicitly return the cast value as a Collection when retrieving it. Instead, by default, it only transforms the enum values back into the enum instances as an array.
To get the expected Collection<JobCategory> type when reading the attribute, you can override the accessor for the subscribed_categories attribute in your model:
use Illuminate\Support\Collection

public function getSubscribedCategoriesAttribute(): Collection
{
    $value = $this->attributes['subscribed_categories'];

    return collect(json_decode($value, true))->map(fn($value) => JobCategory::from($value));
}

